# Get least 10 values in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: Database table.]

I have a table in mysql. Table Name is constitutive_table, it contains more than 40 columns and its type is varchar, it contains more than 25000 records. I wrote the query like this to get the 10 least value. But it showing like as you have seen in the picture.

```
SELECT `Sequence_Name`
     , `Name_of_the_Protein`
     , `Brain` 
  FROM `constitutive_table` 
 where `Brain` != 0 
 ORDER 
    BY cast(Brain AS int) 
 LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Just use `order by Brain`.  Why are you converting to an `int`?

Comment: Brain type is varchar. the value stored in an integer/decimal format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the `Brain` column appears to be floating point, so you should be casting to the appropriate type:

```
SELECT Sequence_Name, Name_of_the_Protein, Brain
FROM constitutive_table
WHERE CAST(Brain AS DECIMAL(14, 8)) <> 0
ORDER BY CAST(Brain AS DECIMAL(14, 8))
LIMIT 10
```

Most likely what is happening now is that the 10 values you see all have the same value when cast to integer.  As a result, MySQL is using some secondary sort to generate the order you do see.

While the above query may resolve your problem, ideally you should change the `Brain` column to some numeric type.